# Format SDCARD in android Studio

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card

I want to Format SD card of android phone using my Application. I have tried many method and came_accross many Questions/Answers in this Site ,But unfortunately None of them works for me .Any help would be appreciated ,Thanks.

```
     File deleteMatchingFile = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

    Log.i("hello",deleteMatchingFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        File[] filenames = deleteMatchingFile.listFiles();
        if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
            for (File tempFile : filenames) {

                Log.i("hello12",tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {

                    wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                    //tempFile.delete();
                } else {
                    tempFile.delete();
                }
            }
        } else {
            deleteMatchingFile.delete();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here is code to wipeDirectories but it does not work

```
         private static void wipeDirectory(String name) {
    File directoryFile = new File(name);
    File[] filenames = directoryFile.listFiles();
    if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
        for (File tempFile : filenames) {
            if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                tempFile.delete();
            } else {
                tempFile.delete();
            }
        }
    } else {
        directoryFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you try to format anything? The current code only removes files, and you haven't explained what is missing

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited my Question and add wipe directory mothod code..please help

Comment: Still, you haven't explained what happens when this code is executed. Is there any error message given? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase it just format the Mobile Internal Storage not the SDCard Storage Although I wrot File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory).thanks